# Massively Reduce Meteor Traffic - Meteor for IoT data tarifs

Tags: javascript, rest, meteor

I run a Meteor Cordova App for 24 h 7 days a week on a client.

I have an IoT data tarif that allows 1MB a month + additional data for Hot Code Push (HCP).

And I don't want to miss HCP.

Problem is: the DDP heartbeat of Meteor alone needs 5MB a month (if I calculated right).

So what is the best way to accomplish this?

- Is it possible to disable the heartbeat? How does DDP behave then?
- If I use a REST API via HTTP for all traffic. How do I start a HCP?

Thanks for  your ideas.